# Can I split Dirac functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, dirac-delta

I’m doing some calculations with Dirac delta function and I don’t know if I can split te function. I’ll show in a picture[image]

Edit1: The integral I was talking about is: $$\int \mathrm{d^4}{p}\,\mathrm{d^4}{q}\,\mathrm{d^4}{w}\,\mathrm{d^4}{\gamma}\,\phi(p)\phi(q)\phi(w)\phi(\gamma){\delta (p+q+w+{\gamma)}}$$

Comment: With the standard definition of $\delta(f)$, what you have is the same as the iterated integral:
$$\iint_{\mathbb R^2} \delta(x + y) \phi(x, y) \, [(x, y) \in D] \, dx dy =
\int_{\mathbb R} \phi(-y, y) \, [(-y, y) \in D] \, dy.$$
This doesn't depend on the order in which you evaluate the single integrals. If $D$ isn't the whole space, there is an extra requirement that the intersection of $\partial D$ with $x + y = 0$ is zero-dimensional, otherwise there is the same ambiguity as with $\int_0^a \delta(x) dx$.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, I really don't think so. Your $\delta$ cares about whether $p+q+w+\gamma$ is $0$, and you can't really separate that into conditions on each of the variables by themselves (or in smaller combinations) in any nice way.

Comment: Even if this delta is on an integral with respect of each argument?

Comment: @alvaro.louzi write down the integral in the question. It is impossible to solve a problem out of context.

Comment: Sorry, I've posted this question in my phone, so it's was really hard to write in Latex. I'll edit the question.